# making hexbin in matplotlib python fill in empty space on a square axis?

Tags: python, matlab, graph, plot, matplotlib

I'm trying to use hexbin to plot some data on a square axis. I use the following:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm                              
plt.figure()  
num_pts = 1000             
x = rand(num_pts) * 100                                                                          
y = rand(num_pts) * 250              
x_min = 0               
x_max = 150                       
x_step = 25

y_min = 50           
y_max = 300                          
y_step = 50       

s = plt.subplot(1,1,1)                                                                                                                              
plt.hexbin(x,y,cmap=cm.jet,gridsize=20)             
plt.xticks(range(x_min,x_max+x_step,x_step))                                                                                                                           
plt.yticks(range(y_min,y_max+y_step,y_step))                                                                                                                           
# square axes                
s.axes.set_aspect(1/s.axes.get_data_ratio())
```

I'd like the axes to be square and I want to set my own xticks/yticks and x-y limits. for some of the axes values, there won't be data and so the counts computed by hexbin should be zero for those -- I would like hexbin to plot that as empty space, rather than leave it "white" / blank if you use the cm.jet colormap.

What I get now is this.

How can I get it to fill the empty space using its colormap?  thanks.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the answer is to use the extent= keyword argument, as in:

```
plt.hexbin(x, y, cmap=cm.jet, gridsize = 20, extent=[x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max])
```

Comment: So helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just create an axis and set its background color to the minimum colormap value (or any color you desire):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,axisbg=cm.jet(0))
```